# Как преобразовать массив символов в полноценную строку?

Tags: c++, массивы, строки

Как преобразовать массив `char` в строку в С++? Допустим, дано:

```
char str[1000]; 
int i = 0;
n[i] = getchar();
while (n[i] != '\n') {
    i++;
    n[i] = getchar();
}
```

Как теперь полученный массив преобразовать в строку?

Comment: Полученный - это какой? `str` или `n`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
string s = str;
```

И всё.

Но куда проще не писать все это, а написать

```
string s;
getline(cin,s);
```

Эффект тот же :)

Кстати, и в самом первом случае я бы просто написал, если уж так хочется через массив работать:

```
char str[1000] = { 0 };
fgets(str,1000,stdin);
```

Comment: мне нужно знать, что вводит пользователь. То есть если он вводит пробел - я должен выдать надпись, мол не надо так делать. А cin считывает только до пробела

Comment: Проверьте для начала...

Answer (score 0):

Так как в данном случае массив предварительно не занулялся, то есть два способа

```
string s(str, i);
```

либо добавить явно ноль и потом сделать присваивание

```
i++;
str[i] = '\0';
string s(str);
```

Способ, предложенный Harry  - имеет багу:) он может добавлять мусорные символы в конец строки в лучшем случае.

Comment: Способ Harry делает ровно то, что запрошено - преобразует массив в строку. **Тот, который дал автор** Где он поставит завершение - там и будет :) А вообще, начнем с того, что автор читает совсем в другой массив, в `n`, а не в `str`...

Comment: проще на этапе инициализации эту проблему решить: `char str[1000] = {};`. Ну и проверку на количество введённых символов тоже надо, но это уже к автору вопроса.

Answer (score 0):

Можно сделать так

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main(){
char buf[] = "Hello, World!";
std::string str;
str = buf;
std::cout << str << std::endl;
return 0;
}
```